# Validate data sent as a request in json

Tags: python, json

I am working on a lambda code for an API in AWS. I am passing a json data within my body which is
shown like this when I print  my event within the lambda.

```
    'body': '{\r\n  "STTN": "415263",\r\n  "Account": "22568758"\r\n}\r\n',
```

Here is how I am validating within the lambda

```
    try:
        eventJson['body']['STTN'] 
    except Exception:       
        returnValidateConditional  = False
        validationResponse['apiStatus'] = "failed" 
        validationResponse['apiErrorCode'] ="1"
        validationResponse['apiDescription'] = "STTN is required" 
        statusCode = 415
        return [returnValidateConditional, validationResponse, statusCode] 
        
    try:
        eventJson['body']['Account'] 
    except Exception:       
        returnValidateConditional  = False
        validationResponse['apiStatus'] = "failed" 
        validationResponse['apiErrorCode'] ="1"
        validationResponse['apiDescription'] = "Account is required" 
        statusCode = 415
        return [returnValidateConditional, validationResponse, statusCode]
```

My validation fails all the time despite the fact that STTN and Account are not empty. They have values
that exist in the body request. All I get is STTN is required

How can I validate json items in the body sent as a request?

Comment: body value is a `str`, so you need to json.loads it

Answer (score 0):

I can notice a few immediate issues with the code:

- Your `'body'` value is of type `str` (string), so it won't work if you subscript it.
- When you use `try: ... except Exception: ...` you are masking the actual error, which is `TypeError`. I would suggest better error handling, such as printing (or [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)) the actual exception/error message. A good start would be `except Exception as e:`, followed by something like `print(e)`.
- a *try/except* block is not a good idea for this use case, where it looks like you just need to check if required keys exist in the request `dict` object. I would suggest using the `in` operator instead.

Repro'd example in REPL:

```py
>>> event = {'body': '{\r\n  "STTN": "415263",\r\n  "Account": "22568758"\r\n}\r\n'}
>>> event['body']
'{\r\n  "STTN": "415263",\r\n  "Account": "22568758"\r\n}\r\n'
>>> type(event['body'])
<class 'str'>
>>> event['body']['STTN']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```

**Solution**: you can use `json.loads` on the `str` value to convert it to a `dict` object

```py
from json import loads

event = {'body': '{\r\n  "STTN": "415263",\r\n  "Account": "22568758"\r\n}\r\n'}


def main():
    # body = event['body']
    body = loads(event['body'])

    print(type(body))   # <class 'dict'>
    try:
        print(body.get('STTN'))  # 415263

        for required_field in ('STTN', 'Account'):
            if required_field not in body:
                validation_response = {'apiStatus': 'failed', 'apiErrorCode': '1',
                                      'apiDescription': f'{required_field} is required'}
                status_code = 415
                return [False, validation_response, status_code]

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'caught a {type(e).__name__}: {e}')
        raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`eventJson['body']` is a string. You need to parse it first

```
try:
    body = json.loads(eventJson['body'].strip().replace(r'\r\n', '')) 
    if not ('STTN' in body and 'Account' in body):
        raise ValueError('Missing STTN or Account fields')
except Exception:
    ...
```

Comment: The validation is still failing with this json.loads. Is your code checking the value?

Comment: What do you mean "the value"? This is a re-write of your code, not "my" code. Yes, the validation will still "fail" if the STTN or Account keys are missing from the JSON

Comment: Looking at your question again, `\r\n` need to be removed from the body. Have editted question with one solution